# Calculate means of variables indexed by preceding dates using R

Tags: r, date, indexing

I would like to generate a data frame of mean temperatures that were recorded on preceding dates using R.

For example, if the dataframe includes:

```
Date,        Temperature
2009-08-15   15
2009-08-16   14
2009-08-17   10
2009-08-18   17
2009-08-19   15
2009-08-20   14
2009-08-21   15
2009-08-22   13
2009-08-23   11
2009-08-24   18
```

I would like to create a new data frame that includes:

```
Date,       Temperature,   2day_Mean_Temp,   5day_Mean_Temp
2009-08-15   15            NA                NA
2009-08-16   14            14.5              NA
2009-08-17   10            12                NA
2009-08-18   17            13.5              NA
2009-08-19   15            16                14.2
2009-08-20   14            14.5              14
2009-08-21   15            14.5              14.2
2009-08-22   13            14                14.8
2009-08-23   11            12                13.6
2009-08-24   18            14.5              14.2
```

The `2day_Mean_Temp` would be the mean of all the temperatures recorded on the date and the day before, and the `5day_Mean_Temp` would be the mean of all the temperatures recorded on and the date and the four days before.

I am not sure how to calculate the `2day_Mean` and `5day_Mean`. Could it be done by indexing by date? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Please provide us reproducible example. Try to share a snippet of your input, what you've done (code), and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Use the code below for your desired output

      for(j in 2:length(df$state)){
      df$twoday_Mean_Temp[j] <- (df$state[j]+df$state[j-1])/2
    }

    for(j in 5:length(df$state)){
      df$fiveday_Mean_Temp[j] <- (sum(df$state[j-1:4])+df$state[j])/5
    }

    print(df)

             Date state twoday_Mean_Temp fiveday_Mean_Temp
    1  2009-08-15    15               NA                NA
    2  2009-08-16    14             14.5                NA
    3  2009-08-17    10             12.0                NA
    4  2009-08-18    17             13.5                NA
    5  2009-08-19    15             16.0              14.2
    6  2009-08-20    14             14.5              14.0
    7  2009-08-21    15             14.5              14.2
    8  2009-08-22    13             14.0              14.8
    9  2009-08-23    11             12.0              13.6
    10 2009-08-24    18             14.5              14.2
```